# Live Agent Chat email to user after chat ended

Tags: liveagent

I have a requirement of sending an email to the user, once the Live Agent, ends a chat. I have a 
pre chat form page, where in I will taking the user's email id. I need to send an email to this email id, once the agent ends the chat.

It would be great if any suggestions are provided. Thanks in advance.

regards,
PH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already stored the email in the Live Chat Transcript, all you would need to do is to create a workflow rule on that object to send an email to that email address.

Comment: Thanks-- The pre chat form I am using, is as below. How should I trigger the email, after the session has been ended by the live agent user?Where will the user email gets saved? I used this code from a forum

<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript:Contact"
        value="ContactId" />

Comment: The transcript is created when the chat ends, at that point your workflow rule would fire and send the email. The email will be saved on whatever field you created in the transcript object, there are clear examples on the live agent developer guide and on this site about how to save a value in a filed in the transcript.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did not find any record getting created. There are two transripts. LIVE AGENT TRANSCRIPT and LIVE AGENT TRANSCRIPT EVENT. Which one should I use?

Comment: Live Agent Ttranscript

Comment: Well my requirement says that, I should not save the transcript. So I have disabled that feature. But I need to send an email to that user after the chat.

Comment: I have another requirement of rearranging the fields, displayed on the CUstom Details box of the Live Agent. I am not understanding, how this box is displayed. It is not displaying the values in the order of input, entered in pre chat form.
Please suggest me something as this is the last set of requirement

Comment: @user3303348 If my previous comments answered your question, please accept the answer to help other people looking for the same information. Also, please create another a different question with your second query.

Comment: My Bad. I just did as per your comment. Thanks a ton again